# Calculating %diff between 2 values in Presto

Tags: presto

I have a field `type double` called `values`.

I want to calculate the `%diff` between **last value** and the **one before last value**, for example:

```
value
10
2
4
2
```

**the output should be:**  `-50%`

How can I do this in presto?

Comment: is there any field like timestamp you can use for ordering to determine value position?

Comment: yes! I have a date field that I can use for ordering

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field for ordering (otherwise result is not guaranteed) you can use [`lag`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) window function:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset ("values", date) AS (
    VALUES (10, now()),
        (4, now() + interval '1' hour),
        (2, now() + interval '2' hour)
) 

--query
select ("values" - l) * 100.0 / l as value
from(
        select "values",
            lag("values") over(order by date) as l,
            date
        from dataset
    )
order by date desc
limit 1
```

Output:

| value |
| --- |
| -50.0 |